# Interpolate a plot on certain intervals only

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, smoothing

Interpolation overshoots the data at zeros

Attempting a vertical plot (x vs. y) with a smooth curvature of the data along the y axis. Tried SciPy.interpolate's splev and splrep on the entire graph (y[0]-y[-1]). On this interval, the x data is positive, oscillating, and drops to zero several times. The interpolation goes negative (overshoots) at zeros. Here's a sample of the data:

```
e = np.array([-0.65067307, -0.61057307, -0.57057307, -0.53057307, -0.49047307,
              -0.45047307, -0.41037307, -0.37037307, -0.33037307, -0.29027307,
              -0.25027307, -0.21017307, -0.17017307, -0.13017307, -0.09007307,
              -0.05007307, -0.00997307,  0.03002693,  0.07002693,  0.11012693,
               0.15012693,  0.19022693,  0.23022693,  0.27022693,  0.31032693])

x = np.array([0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
              0.    , 1.1015, 3.0956, 2.2363, 2.4597, 1.8997, 1.5912, 1.6496,
              0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
              0.    ])

y = np.arange(e[0],e[-1],0.001)
spl = splrep(e,x)
xDat = splev(y,spl)
plt.plot(x,e,'k.',xDat,y,'r-',lw=0.5)
```

I need the graph to be smooth but not oscillate about zeros. It should die out abruptly at zeros. I'm thinking of limiting the smoothing algorithm to intervals of nonzero (or at least above some cutoff value) data. Looking for other opinions on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Check it out...

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

y = np.arange(e[0],e[-1],0.001)
l = [0 if i==0 else 1 for i in interp1d(e,x)(y)]
xDat = splev(y,splrep(e,x)) * l
plt.plot(x,e,'k.',xDat[xDat>=0],y[xDat>=0],'r-',lw=0.5)
```

Used linear interpolation to generate a step function enclosing the nonzero data. Multiplying the actual data by this function and plotting only positive values did the trick. Thanks for the tip on conditional slicing...

Comment: I have a small query, can we pass multiple Y values for the same x in splrep for interpolation?